# ASP.NET Core SqlException: the insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created two tables (Customer, Sale) with one to many relationship in my application (ASP.NET Core application) where one customer have many sales invoices, but when create a sale, I get error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Sale_Customer_customerId". The conflict occurred in database "LibraryBookManagmentDataBase", table "dbo.Customer", column 'Customerid'. The statement has been terminated.

[image]

This is the `Customer` model class:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Customerid { get; set; }
    [Required, MinLength(2), MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double NationalID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sale> Sales { get; set; } 
}
```

This is the `Sale` model class:

```
public class Sale
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Sales Date")]
    public DateTime SalesDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Sales Code")]
    public string SaleCode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Customerid")]
    public int customerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } 
}
```

This is razor page of create new sale

```
<form asp-controller="Sale" asp-action="Create" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name">Customer &nbsp  </label>
                    <select class="form-control border-input" asp-items="ViewBag.Customerid" placeholder = "Customer"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["Customerid"] = new SelectList(customerRepository.PreffedCustomer, "Customerid", "Name");
    ViewData["Bookid"] = new SelectList(BookRepository.Preffedbooks, "Bookid", "Title");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Sale model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        saleRepository.Create(model);
        return RedirectToAction();
    }

    return Json(new { error = true, message = "failed to save Sales" });
}
```

The `Sale` is stored with this method :

```
public void Create(sale entity) 
{ 
    _context.Add(entity); 
    _context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Quite simply: you're trying to insert a `Sale` with a  `CustomerId` that doesn't exist in the `Customer` table -> that's the **whole point** of having foreign key constraints - to avoid such a situation! So fix this - make sure you only use `CustomerId` in  `Sale` that exist in the `Customer` Table .... - database design 101

Comment: @marc_s Did you mean to change Customerid to customerId?

Comment: @marc_s Did you mean to convert Customerid to customerId?

Comment: I mean: **debug your code** and check what value you have for `CustomerId` on the `Sale` object before you save it. **Ensure** that a customer with this value for it's `CustomerId` already exists in the `Customer` table to avoid this mistake

Comment: @marc_s in Custmer table :  [Key]
    public int Customerid { get; set; }

Comment: @marc_s and sale table 
[ForeignKey("Customerid")]
    public int customerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

Comment: You need to check **at runtime**, in your `Create` method that gets called - what is the value  of `model.customerId` ?? And does a customer with that `CustomerId` already exist in the database? The error message you're getting seems to indicate that this is **not** the case - so why are you trying to save a `Sale` object with an invalid / non-existing `CustomerId` ?? That's what you need to figure out ....

Comment: @MostafaGamal ASP.NET Core is a web framework, not a data access library or an ORM. It doesn't read or save any data to the database. That's the job of ADO.NET and EF Core. The code posted here has nothing to do with the error. If you check the stack trace in the full exception text you'll see where the exception is thrown. Post the *full exception text* instead of a screenshot and the code where the exception occurs. The error is pretty clear though - you tried to insert a Sale referencing a non-existent customer. At the very least post the code for `SalesRepository.Create`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  public void Create(sale entity)
        {
            _context.Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: @MostafaGamal the error is still crystal clear - the CustomerID is invalid. Only *you* can debug your code to see what's wrong with it. As for the "generic repository" you use, that's a *very ugly **anti**-pattern*. That method could easily perform 1000 DELETEs along with that single INSERT as `SaveChanges` saves *all* changes inside a single transaction. That "repository" on the other hand forces you to use an explicit transaction if you want to perform multiple changes. You gained nothing by using `SalesRepository`

Comment: Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) to see why that repository isn't just bad for performance, it actually introduces errors like the unexpected operations. This isn't some new idea either, the problems with "repositories" on top of ORMs were known as long as there were ORMs in .NET - Oren Eini's [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) is from 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, I have created a sample, it seems that when insert new Sale entity, if the customerId is null, it will show this "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" error. You can set a break point in the Create HttpPost method to verify it.

> ```
> <select class="form-control border-input" asp-items="ViewBag.Customerid" placeholder = "Customer"></select>
> ```

The issue is related that the select element, since the it doesn't contain the name attribute, when you submit the form, the customer is null ('0' is the default value, in my  database, the customer is start from 1, doesn't contain '0').

[image]

To solve this issue, try to modify the select element code as below :

```
  <select asp-for="customerId" class ="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Customerid" placeholder = "Customer"></select>
```

or

```
   <select name="customerId" class ="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.Customerid" placeholder = "Customer"></select>
```

The result (success):

[image]

**Edit**

Besides, about the ForeignKey attribute, we can use it as below:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
        
    [ForeignKey("Standard")]
    public int StandardRefId { get; set; }
    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

*In the above example, the [ForeignKey] attribute is applied on the StandardRefId and specified in the name of the navigation property Standard. This will create the foreign key column named StandardRefId in the Students table, preventing the generation of a StandardId column in the database.*

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
        
    public int StandardRefId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("StandardRefId")]
    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

*In the above example, the [ForeignKey] attribute is applied on the Standard navigation property and the name of the foreign key property StandardRefId is specified. This will create the foreign key column named StandardRefId in the Students table, preventing the generation of a StandardId column in the database.*

More detail information, see: [Data Annotations - ForeignKey Attribute in EF 6 & EF Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)